# How to set type of generic method in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics, datatable

Is something like that possible:

```
int testvar = 0;
var query = PrimaryDataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(r => 
                r.Field<testvar.GetType()>("col") == testvar);
```

But I don't want this:

```
int testvar = 0;
if (testvar is int)
{
    var query = PrimaryDataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(r => 
                    r.Field<int>("col") == testvar);
}
```

Comment: Of course, but I don't think you will want the complexity of it. I would recommend you revise your question to explain what you want to do, not how you're trying to accomplish it.

Comment: I have a var of with the type "object". I don't now the real type. I have to search with this var in a linq query. But I can't do that because I have to tell the programm wich type the var is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use `Field` to get the value; get it as an object:

```
var query = PrimaryDataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(r => 
    object.Equals(r["col"], testvar));
```

The whole point of using generics is to have static typing when you know the type involved statically.  Since you don't, there's no benefit to using it.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I want to do.